# JFileChooser within a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jfilechooser, tablecelleditor

all I'm attempting to create a new component to go inside of a JTable. It consists of a JTextfield that when clicked on spawns a JFileChooser so the user can browser the file system and select the file that the want and then populate the field with the path to that file. So far I've gotten to the point where I can have the text field fill in the editor but when I click it the FilecChooser doesn't spawn. Anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong here?

```
public class FileBrowserCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor, ActionListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Component frame;
JButton button;
JTextField textField;
String path;
JFileChooser fc;
protected static final String EDIT = "edit";

public FileBrowserCellEditor(Component frame){
    this.frame = frame;

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setActionCommand(EDIT);
    textField.addActionListener(this);

    fc = new JFileChooser();
}

@Override
public Object getCellEditorValue() {

    return path;

}

@Override
public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable arg0, Object arg1,
        boolean arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {

    return textField;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    //Debug
    System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());

    if (EDIT.equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
        //The user has clicked the cell, so
        //bring up the dialog.
        textField.setText(path);
        fc.showOpenDialog(frame);

        fireEditingStopped(); //Make the renderer reappear.

    } else { //User pressed dialog's "OK" button.
        //currentColor = colorChooser.getColor();

            File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
            this.path = file.getAbsolutePath();

    }

}

}
```

Comment: Try doing it as a `MouseListener` instead of an `ActionListener`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple cell editor which displays a `JFileChooser` when double-clicking on the cell:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;

public class FileChooserCellEditor extends DefaultCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {

    /** Number of clicks to start editing */
    private static final int CLICK_COUNT_TO_START = 2;
    /** Editor component */
    private JButton button;
    /** File chooser */
    private JFileChooser fileChooser;
    /** Selected file */
    private String file = "";

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public FileChooserCellEditor() {
        super(new JTextField());
        setClickCountToStart(CLICK_COUNT_TO_START);

        // Using a JButton as the editor component
        button = new JButton();
        button.setBackground(Color.white);
        button.setFont(button.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN));
        button.setBorder(null);

        // Dialog which will do the actual editing
        fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return file;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        file = value.toString();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                fileChooser.setSelectedFile(new File(file));
                if (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(button) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
                }
                fireEditingStopped();
            }
        });
        button.setText(file);
        return button;
    }
}
```

To add it to your `JTable`:

```
yourJTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(yourColumnIndex).setCellEditor(new FileChooserCellEditor());
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can try the following Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.io.*;

class TableFileChooser extends JFrame  
{
    private JTable table;
    private JScrollPane jsPane;
    private TableModel myModel;
    private JPanel dialogPanel;
    private JTextField tf[];
    private JLabel     lbl[];
    public void prepareAndShowGUI()
    {
        setTitle("FileChooser in JTable");
        myModel = new MyModel();
        table = new JTable(myModel);
        jsPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        table.addMouseListener(new MyMouseAdapter());
        getContentPane().add(jsPane);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        prepareDialogPanel();
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

    }
    private void prepareDialogPanel()
    {
        dialogPanel = new JPanel();
        int col = table.getColumnCount() - 1;
        dialogPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(col,2));
        tf = new JTextField[col];
        lbl = new JLabel[col];
        for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
        {
            lbl[i] = new JLabel(table.getColumnName(i));
            tf[i] = new JTextField(10);
            dialogPanel.add(lbl[i]);
            dialogPanel.add(tf[i]);
        }
    }
    private void populateTextField(String[] s)
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < s.length ; i++ )
        {
            tf[i].setText(s[i]);
        }
    }

    private class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter
    {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt)
        {
            int x = evt.getX();
            int y = evt.getY();
            int row = table.rowAtPoint(new Point(x,y));
            int col = table.columnAtPoint(new Point(x,y));
            if (col == 2)
            {
                String value = load();
                if (value!=null && ! "null".equalsIgnoreCase(value.trim()) && ! "".equalsIgnoreCase(value.trim()))
                {
                    myModel.setValueAt(value,row,col);
                }
                else
                {
                    myModel.setValueAt("ChooseFile",row,col);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //Loads the file
    private String load()
    {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(".");
        chooser.setDialogTitle("Open");
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(this);
        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
        {
            File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            if (file!= null)
            {
                return file.getAbsolutePath();
            }
            else 
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Please enter a fileName","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    private class MyModel extends AbstractTableModel 
    {
        String[] columns = {
                            "Roll No.",
                            "Name",
                            "File Name"
                            };
        String[][] inData = {
                                {"1","Anthony Hopkins","ChooseFile"},
                                {"2","James William","ChooseFile"},
                                {"3","Mc. Donald","ChooseFile"}
                            };
        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col)
        {
            inData[row][col] = (String)value;
            fireTableCellUpdated(row,col);
        }
        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col)
        {
            return inData[row][col];
        }
        @Override
        public int getColumnCount()
        {
            return columns.length;
        }
        @Override 
        public int getRowCount()
        {
            return inData.length;
        }
        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int col)
        {
            return columns[col];
        }
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row ,int col)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String st[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                TableFileChooser td = new TableFileChooser();
                td.prepareAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: While this does work I was hoping to implement a solution using the AbstractCellEditor class and not to resort to using a method like this.

Comment: @ChrisManess : you want `JTextField` as cell Editor?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that displays a custom dialog when you edit the cell. You should be able to customize it to use a JFileChooser instead of the custom dialog:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

/*
 * The editor button that brings up the dialog.
 */
//public class TablePopupEditor extends AbstractCellEditor
public class TablePopupEditor extends DefaultCellEditor
    implements TableCellEditor
{
    private PopupDialog popup;
    private String currentText = "";
    private JButton editorComponent;

    public TablePopupEditor()
    {
        super(new JTextField());

        setClickCountToStart(1);

        //  Use a JButton as the editor component

        editorComponent = new JButton();
        editorComponent.setBackground(Color.white);
        editorComponent.setBorderPainted(false);
        editorComponent.setContentAreaFilled( false );

        // Make sure focus goes back to the table when the dialog is closed
        editorComponent.setFocusable( false );

        //  Set up the dialog where we do the actual editing

        popup = new PopupDialog();
    }

    public Object getCellEditorValue()
    {
        return currentText;
    }

    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(
        JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column)
    {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                System.out.println("run");
                popup.setText( currentText );
//              popup.setLocationRelativeTo( editorComponent );
                Point p = editorComponent.getLocationOnScreen();
                popup.setLocation(p.x, p.y + editorComponent.getSize().height);
                popup.show();
                fireEditingStopped();
            }
        });

        currentText = value.toString();
        editorComponent.setText( currentText );
        return editorComponent;
    }

    /*
    *   Simple dialog containing the actual editing component
    */
    class PopupDialog extends JDialog implements ActionListener
    {
        private JTextArea textArea;

        public PopupDialog()
        {
            super((Frame)null, "Change Description", true);

            textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
            textArea.setLineWrap( true );
            textArea.setWrapStyleWord( true );
            KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER");
            textArea.getInputMap().put(keyStroke, "none");
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( textArea );
            getContentPane().add( scrollPane );

            JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
            cancel.addActionListener( this );
            JButton ok = new JButton("Ok");
            ok.setPreferredSize( cancel.getPreferredSize() );
            ok.addActionListener( this );

            JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
            buttons.add( ok );
            buttons.add( cancel );
            getContentPane().add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            pack();

            getRootPane().setDefaultButton( ok );
        }

        public void setText(String text)
        {
            textArea.setText( text );
        }

        /*
        *   Save the changed text before hiding the popup
        */
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if ("Ok".equals( e.getActionCommand() ) )
            {
                currentText = textArea.getText();
            }

            textArea.requestFocusInWindow();
            setVisible( false );
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] columnNames = {"Item", "Description"};
        Object[][] data =
        {
            {"Item 1", "Description of Item 1"},
            {"Item 2", "Description of Item 2"},
            {"Item 3", "Description of Item 3"}
        };

        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(300);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        // Use the popup editor on the second column

        TablePopupEditor popupEditor = new TablePopupEditor();
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor( popupEditor );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Popup Editor Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JTextField(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add( scrollPane );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```